# jquery ajax error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery ajax to retrieve some data, but it fails, below are the codes:

```
 $.Webpic_Init = function(){
        var type = 'default';
        $.ajax({
            url:SITE_PATH+"services/service.php?m=share&a=uploadwebpic&photo_type="+type,
            type: "POST",
            data:{ name: "John", location: "Boston" },
            cache:false,
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(result){
                alert(result);
            },
            error:function(){
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    }
```

this alerts 'error'. 
But if I change the url parameter to 'SITE_PATH+"services/service.php"', the 'success' event was dispatched. So what can I do, if I don't want to change the url parameter?

Comment: Can you monitor the request with chrome network tab or FF's firebug net tab and check whats going wrong, like response code etc?, or share an url so that we can check if thats possible.

Comment: What is the value of SITE_PATH and is it on the same domain as the page this code is in?

Comment: So what your basicly saying is that the URL is not correct, and it works if you change the URL, and for some reason it actually works if you add a new set of quotes making your variables into strings that are part of the URL, but what you'd really like to know is what you can do to make it work with the URL you have? The answer seems obvious, change the location of the file to match your URL, or change the URL to match the location of the file ?

Comment: Everytime I look at your URL, a kitten dies.

Comment: It is so strange that it displays the response result in chrome network tab. But still alerts 'error'.

Comment: What are you getting in your response result?

Comment: I print the $_POST value in php file, and it shows me the correct result:Array([name]=>John, [location]=>Boston).

Comment: Is there some particular reason why you have accepted only 1 answer out of 11 eligible answers that were provided to your previous questions?

Answer (score 0):

You are making a POST request all your fields should be in the data object like you have made.

```
data:{ name: "John", location: "Boston" }
```

You should not be putting anything on the url. Thats for GET request.

Comment: It seem that I need to convert the php array to json format.I did this in the php file: echo json_encode($_POST); It works.

Answer (score 0):

Prepend `/` in the url instead of adding `SITE_PATH`. This will make the URL relative to the domain i.e. relative to `www.your-domain.com/`. If the `services` is within some sub folder you can do it like `/sub_folder_name/services/your_path_continue`

Answer (score 0):

```
        var type = 'default';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'services/service.php',
            type: "POST", dataType: "json",
            data: { 'm': 'share', 'a': 'uploadwebpic', 'photo_type': type, 'typename': "John", 'location': "Boston" },
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            cache: false,           
            success: function (data) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
```

Comment: it is put one break point in service.php on post? then see it is firing or not.

Comment: url is internal or external path?

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, try using the [$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to get the correct error like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This would help you to properly handle the Ajax error and get the exact error that occurred while making the ajax call.